# Trouble parsing this json format

Tags: android, json

```
jsonUptimeRobotApi({"stat": "ok","account":{"monitorLimit":"50", "monitorInterval":"5", "upMonitors":"23", "downMonitors":"1", "pausedMonitors":"0"}})
```

Can anybody tell me a way to parse it.

Comment: That is technically not JSON, its a JavaScript callback containing JSON data. This is used for cross domain requests on websites. For Android apps, don't ask for a callback (usually ?callback=jsonUptimeRobotApi), or read the API docs to see if there is a way to explicitly disable the callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks a lot like Flickrs response with their jsonFlickrApi().

Maybe you can read the documentation, you can add this to the Flickr calls to receive a normal JSON `&nojsoncallback=1`.

Or if all else fails, you could do something like this:

```
String jsonResponse = "jsonUptimeRobotApi({"stat": "ok","account":{"monitorLimit":"50", "monitorInterval":"5", "upMonitors":"23", "downMonitors":"1", "pausedMonitors":"0"}})";
int startIndex = jsonResponse.indexOf("(") + 1;
int endIndex = jsonResponse.lastIndexOf(")") - 1;
jsonResponse = jsonResponse.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
```

Again, I would recommend against this approach, but this will probably get you what you want.

Comment: As I said, just add this to the URL you are calling: `&noJsonCallback=1` Like so: `http://api.uptimerobot.com/getAccountDetails?apiKey=XXXXX&format=json&noJsonCallback=1`. Recommend you remove your API key :).

Comment: that didnt work and can u please elaborate what u meant by removing the api key

Comment: Well according to their documentation, that **MUST** work. And I meant, remove the API key from your comment, so people don't see it :).

Comment: No problem, consider accepting the answer if it worked :).